# Google Script returning ‘Exception: Empty Response’ when running BigQuery query via API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am using a Google Script within Google Sheets to run a query (via Bigquery) and return the results to the same spreadsheet. It is all working fine for queries where I have a narrow date range for the data but when I extend the date range beyond a couple of weeks, I receive the error: ‘Exception: Empty Response’. Both queries are otherwise exactly the same and are the same size to process when I run them manually in BigQuery (although the Rows Input / Output are larger in the job explanation for the extended date range query). Does anyone know what is causing this error and how I might fix this?

Execution transcript for unsuccessful query i.e when query includes WHERE user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros BETWEEN 1509494400000000 AND 1511395200000000:

> [17-11-28 02:15:13:072 PST] Starting execution
>
> [17-11-28 02:15:13:085 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
>
> [17-11-28 02:15:13:222 PST] Sheet.getRange([C183]) [0.136 seconds]
>
> [17-11-28 02:15:13:284 PST] Range.getValue() [0.062 seconds]
>
> [17-11-28 02:16:13:278 PST] Logger.log([Exception: Empty response, []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [17-11-28 02:16:16:565 PST] Browser.msgBox([Exception: Empty response]) [3.286 seconds]
>
> [17-11-28 02:16:16:609 PST] Execution succeeded [63.483 seconds total runtime]

Execution transcript for successful query i.e when query includes WHERE user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros BETWEEN 1510444800000000 AND 1511395200000000:

> [17-11-28 01:49:51:604 PST] Starting execution
>
> [17-11-28 01:49:51:614 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
>
> [17-11-28 01:49:51:672 PST] Sheet.getRange([C183]) [0.057 seconds]
>
> [17-11-28 01:49:51:730 PST] Range.getValue() [0.057 seconds]
>
> [17-11-28 01:50:31:816 PST] Sheet.getRange([1, 20, 1, 43]) [0 seconds]
>
> [17-11-28 01:50:31:896 PST] Range.setValues([[[20737, 7342, 3061, 872, 1076, 924, 322, 170, 36, 54, 79, 928, 224, 21, 50, 8645, 3364, 749, 2060, 1051, 609, 226, 44, 51, 175, 924, 192, 22, 49, 1263, 515, 96, 99, 82, 32, 11, 0, 3, 21, 148, 35, 1, 0]]]...) [0.08 seconds]
>
> [17-11-28 01:50:34:394 PST] Browser.msgBox([Press OK to see results]) [2.497 seconds]
>
> [17-11-28 01:50:34:516 PST] Execution succeeded [42.781 seconds total runtime]

The script is below (with projectNumber removed):

```
function runQuery1() {
var projectNumber = ‘XXXXXXXX';
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var cell1 = sheet.getRange("C183").getValue();
var sql = cell1;
var queryResults;
  
// Inserts a Query Job
try {
var queryRequest = BigQuery.newQueryRequest();
queryRequest.setQuery(sql).setUseLegacySql(false).setTimeoutMs(999999);
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(queryRequest, projectNumber);
}
catch (err) {
Logger.log(err);
Browser.msgBox(err);
return;
}

// Check on status of the Query Job
while (queryResults.getJobComplete() == false) {
try {
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectNumber, queryJob.getJobReference().getJobId());
}
catch (err) {
Logger.log(err);
Browser.msgBox(err);
return;
}
}

// Update the amount of results
var resultCount = queryResults.getTotalRows();
var resultSchema = queryResults.getSchema();
  
var resultValues = new Array(resultCount);
var tableRows = queryResults.getRows();

Iterate through query results
for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
var cols = tableRows[i].getF();
resultValues[i] = new Array(cols.length);

// For each column, add values to the result array
for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
resultValues[i][j] = cols[j].getV();
}
} 

// Update the Spreadsheet with data from the resultValues array, starting from cell A1
sheet.getRange(1, 20, resultCount, tableRows[0].getF().length).setValues(resultValues);  
Browser.msgBox("Press OK to see results");
}
```